# Update a picklist value with a text field's value using workflow

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to update a picklist field (contains list of month from January to December )value with a text field that holds correct month value. could you please help me with the correct syntax? thanks

Comment: I removed the salesforce-communities and salesforce-crm tags since your question doesn't have anything to do with either one. A [tag](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags) is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a Picklist value to a String inside a Trigger (doesn't even have to match the available values -- though you might want to validate it before setting).

Inside a before insert/update trigger you could do the following (assuming this is an Account):

```
for (Account a : Trigger.new)
{
  a.MonthPicklist = a.MonthText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this currently, but if you watch this dreamforce session, it sounds like it is coming in Spring '14.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kyn81zd8TVE&t=51m55s (#safeharbor)  Follow this group on the success community for more info on what is upcoming in Spring '14: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001okuCAA