# How do you update a text field based on a Picklist field but still let the text field be editable?

Tags: trigger, workflow, inputfield

I'm new to SF so apologies as I imagine this question has been asked before but each answer I read I unfortunately "don't get it".

I have a normal picklist field (Picklist A), where the user can choose a value. I then have another text field (text B), where I want it to update to certain text based on the value picked in "Picklist A" BUT still be editable by the user if they disagree with that value.

I've tried a default field, but it tells me I can't use the value in Picklist A (makes sense as I assume default field is generated on edit of the form) I also looked at a formula but of course then its un-editable.

I did try a work flow rule but it didn't update so maybe its used for something else? Would love to hear thoughts for a salesforce newb.

I did see this answer which looked like it may be an incoming feature from 7 years ago? I'm hoping not to use a trigger/apex as I haven't reached that part of learning yet.
[Update a picklist value with a text field's value using workflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23070/update-a-picklist-value-with-a-text-fields-value-using-workflow)

Thanks so much.

Comment: This is an exceedingly broad question. What part of the workflow rule didn't work?  Perhaps you should be researching how workflows work and work out why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Workflow or Process Builder. For process builder you add the conditions:

- Picklist A equals Value A -> with action -> Text equals 'add
  something as string'
- Picklist B equals Value B -> with action -> Text
  equals 'add something else as string'

Keep in mind that this will override the current value in you Text field every time someone changes the picklist value.

You can do the same thing using Apex Trigger using the moment you want this modification to be made (before record insert, after record update) (More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

You will need something like this:

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (before insert) {
   
  for(ObjectName varName : Trigger.new) {
    if(varName.Picklist == 'Value A') {
      varName.Text = 'Add something as string'
    } else if(varName.Picklist == 'Value B') {
      varName.Text = 'Add something else as string'
    }
  }

}
```

Just change the name of the variable, TriggerName and ObjectName(here add the object you are working on, like Account, Contact, CustomObject__c). Do this trailhead module for more information about how to use triggers: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I ended up getting it to work through the Workflow Rules, but knowing the process builder now I might change to that. Definitely will like to try the trigger as I read you can trigger more then just on save. Super appreciate the trailhead links as a learner as well!